# Place legend without border above the plot

Tags: legending, plotting, version-7

I use **Mathematica 7.0** and as far as I know, there is not method PlotLegends, only PlotLegend. I want to set my legend - without background, shadow and frame - **above** my plot, as in the example belowe: [image]

I found the commend, which helps to reduce shadow, but I don't know how to make other settings. The main problem is that all information which I found are for `PlotLegends` which is not used in Mathematica 7

My plot
[image]

My code:

```
ListPlot[{top, bottom},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[100]],
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"Number of non-zero bits", "alpha"},
 Axes -> False,
 LegendSize -> 0.5,
 LegendShadow -> None,
 PlotLegend -> {Style["exact value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130], 
   Style["estimated value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130]},
 LegendPosition -> {0 - .60, 0.30},
 PlotRange -> {0, 20},
 ImageSize -> 7000,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly close to what you're after.  For version 7 use `ColorData[1, ...]` for the right colour set.

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];

ShowLegend[Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 3},
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500],
 {{{Graphics[{ColorData[97, 1], Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {8, 0}}]}],
    Style["long text 1", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
   {Graphics[{ColorData[97, 2], Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {8, 0}}]}],
    Style["long text 2", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
   {Graphics[{ColorData[97, 3], Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {8, 0}}]}],
    Style["long text 3", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}},
  LegendPosition -> {-1, 0.65}, LegendSize -> {2.1, 0.22},
  LegendShadow -> False, LegendBorderSpace -> 0.1, LegendTextSpace -> 0.6,
  LegendOrientation -> Horizontal, LegendBorder -> None}]
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have same features of PlotLegends in Mathematica 11?

Comment: @GaeP The example still works in Mathematica 11, but it *is* legacy code  You can use ```Quiet@Needs["PlotLegends`"]``` to suppress the warning messages.  I expect the same result can be obtained using the newer `PlotLegend` functionality.  I will see if I can add an example.

Comment: Thanks! this code doesn't work in M11.

Comment: @GaeP I just ran it in 11.0 and 11.2 on Windows.  Did you include the `Needs` statement?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. Have i download any package?

Comment: @GaeP No, it's self-contained.  I don't know why it doesn't work on your setup.